# Custom authorizer not being invoked for websocket connect event

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, websocket, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to implement a custom authorizer for an API Gateway Websocket API.

I have my custom authorizer declared like so using CDK:

```
const authFunc = new lambda.Function(scope, utils.prefixed("WebsocketAuth"), {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
    handler: `auth.handler`,
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(lambdaPath),
    environment: {
        API_KEY_ID: apiKey.keyId
    }
});

const authorizer = new WebSocketLambdaAuthorizer(
    "WebsocketAuth",
    authFunc
);

const webSocketApi = new apigatewayv2.WebSocketApi(scope, 'WebSocketApi', {
    connectRouteOptions: {
        authorizer,
        integration: new integrations.WebSocketLambdaIntegration('ConnectHandler', connectFunc),
    },
    disconnectRouteOptions: {
        integration: new integrations.WebSocketLambdaIntegration('DisconnectHandler', disconnectFunc)
    },
    defaultRouteOptions: {
      integration: new integrations.WebSocketLambdaIntegration('DefaultHandler', defaultFunc),
    },
    routeSelectionExpression: '$request.body.action',
});
```

When I try to connect to this Websocket API, I get a connection closure callback with code 1006.  However when I check the cloudwatch logs, there is no log group for my custom authroizer, so it seems as if the lambda is not being invoked as expected.

I connect like so:

```
ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${host}/${stage}?token=${authToken}`);
```

Before adding the custom authorizer, the websocket connection succeeded, and the API worked as expected.

I am able to execute the custom authorizer lambda using the `Test` function in the console, and logs are created as expected.

Here is the implementation of the authorizer handler:

```
import { APIGatewayRequestAuthorizerEvent, APIGatewayAuthorizerResult } from 'aws-lambda';

const secret = process.env.API_SECRET ?? '';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayRequestAuthorizerEvent): Promise<APIGatewayAuthorizerResult> => {

    console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

    const query = event.queryStringParameters ?? { token: 'NONE' };
    const token = query['token'];

    console.log(`Query: ${JSON.stringify(query)}`);

    if (token === secret) {
        console.log(`Allowed`);
        return generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn);
    } else {
        console.log(`Denied`);
        return generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn);
    }

};

function generatePolicy(principalId: string, effect: string, resource: string) {
    return {
        principalId,
        policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
            {
                Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
                Effect: effect,
                Resource: resource,
            },
        ],
        },
    };
}
```

What am I missing to make this custom authorizer work?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I had to add the `identitySource` argument to the `WebSocketLambdaAuthorizer` declaration:

```
const authorizer = new WebSocketLambdaAuthorizer(
    "WebsocketAuth",
    authFunc,
    {
        identitySource: ['route.request.querystring.token']
    }
);
```

This is required, because apparently the authorizer will not be invoked if the fields in the `identitySource` are not present, and the default `identitySource` is the `Authorization` header, which is not easily set for websocket connections.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. This saved me time troubleshooting my WebSocket API GW and CUSTOM/Lambda authorizator. The AWS document for AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer and its IdentitySource starts with words: "For a REQUEST authorizer, this is optional". So I had just stopped reading at that point - Big mistake :)